# What does あの子、あんなんだしさ mean?

Tags: spoken-language, phrases, manga

Would you please tell me what あの子、あんなんだしさ means?
and then she said あの子を理解してあげられる人なんて　たぶんごく僅かだと思うのよ。。。
The person who said this phrase is a mother talking with her son's friend about her son.

Thank you in advance

Comment: More context would be appreciated.

Comment: "My son is such one"? As 永劫回帰 san is telling, more context would help the answerers.

Comment: Without the preceding context needed to identify who is being talked about and the relation to the speaker (probably a child of the speaker's as others have said). A loose and idiomatic translation:
"The boy's just always doing things like that... you could probably count on one hand the number of people who take the time to understand what really makes him tick".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means something like

> He's always like that

- あの子 (or この子 if the child is nearby) is a standard way of referring to your own child in conversation.
- (だし)さ is displaying a mild concern (he's always playing with his food, he's always getting his clothes dirty, etc.)
- し is actually the listing particle ～し～し, but often used by itself for emphasis in colloquial speech, implying there are many more things she (presumably as mother) is concerned about
- あんなんだ = あんな+ん+だ, where あんな (sibling of こんな and そんな) means "such a"
- ん = の is "one" (as in "the red one")

Comment: 「あんなんだ(し)」の意味は「あんなのだ(から)」「あんなふうだ(から)」とか「あんな調子だ(から)」に近いかなと思います